# Flex/Lex reading from a input file

Tags: c++, file, flex-lexer

I have a Lex program that reads if a given character is an alphabet or number. How to I take my inputs directly from a file. This is my simple program. Also what would be a good tutorial for Flex/Lex

```
%{
#include<stdio.h>
%}

%%

[a-zA-Z]+   printf("Token Type: STRINGLITERAL \n Value: [%s] ",yytext);
[0-9]+ printf("Token Type: INTLITERAL \n VALUE:[%s]", yytext);

.   printf("[%s] is not a word",yytext);


%%

int main(void)
{
    yylex();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How do I read tokens  such as say, 'program'/'end'/'if' etc... And how do I prevent it from being read as a STRING LITERAL as well? 
Thanks again

Comment: You may want to add a line to ignore space.

Answer (score 2):

I Like the C++ output from flex.

### Lexer.l

```
%option c++

%{

#include <string>
#include <iostream>

%}

WhiteSpace          [ \t]

%%

[A-Za-z]+           {std::cout << "WORD:  " << std::string(yytext, yyleng) << "\n";   return 1;}
[0-9]+              {std::cout << "Number:" << std::string(yytext, yyleng) << "\n";   return 2;}

{WhiteSpace}+       {/*IgnoreSpace*/}

.                   {std::cout << "Unknown\n";  return 3;}


%%

int yyFlexLexer::yywrap()
{
    return true;
}
```

Build Like this:

```
flex --header-file=Lexer.h -t Lexer.l  > Lexer.cpp
```

Note: I use the above line because I hate the generated files names and this way I get to use file names I like.

Now you can use standard C++ streams (like std::cin and std::ifstream).

```
#include "Lexer.h"

int main()
{
    yyFlexLexer   lex(&std::cin);  // Pass a pointer to any input stream.
    while (lex.yylex())
    {
    }

    std::ifstream  file("text");
    yyFlexLexer    anotherLexer(&file);

    while(anotherLexer.yylex())
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to set the variable `yyin` to the file handler of the file you want to read.

My favorite tutorial on Flex and Bison is [this one](https://aquamentus.com/flex_bison.html#4) from aquamentus.

From that same tutorial, here you have a fragment on how to read from a file using Flex.

```
int main(){
  // open a file handle to a particular file:
  FILE *myfile = fopen("your_file", "r");
  // make sure it's valid:
  if (!myfile) {
    cout << "I can't open the file!" << endl;
    return -1;
  }
  // set lex to read from it instead of defaulting to STDIN:
  yyin = myfile;
  
  // lex through the input:
  while(yylex());
  fclose(myfile);
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to call `fclose(myfile);` after the loop. It may not be very important in this case but better to not neglect such things, in case you switch to a reentrant scanner later.

Answer (score 0):

@KompjoeFriek, thanks for the link :)

@error_404, this code work for me

```
%{
    #include<stdio.h>
%}

%%
[a-zA-Z]+   printf("Token Type: STRINGLITERAL \n Value: [%s] ",yytext);
[0-9]+ printf("Token Type: INTLITERAL \n VALUE:[%s]", yytext);

.   printf("[%s] is not a word",yytext);
%%

int main(int ac, char **av)
{
    FILE    *fd;

    if (ac == 2)
    {
        if (!(fd = fopen(av[1], "r")))
        {
            perror("Error: ");
            return (-1);
        }
        yyset_in(fd);
        yylex();
        fclose(fd);
    }
    else
        printf("Usage: a.out filename\n");
    return (0);
}
```